# rails 3/postgres - how long is a string if you don't apply :limit in schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My googlefu must be weak because I cannot find anything to tell me the default limit of a string column in my Rails app (hosted at Heroku, using PostgreSQL as the database).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ActiveRecord uses `varchar(255)` (or `character varying (255)` to be pedantic) if you don't specify a specific limit. You can always hop into PostgreSQL with `psql` and say `\d your_table` to get the table as PostgreSQL sees it.

I don't think the default is specified anywhere but it is [right here in the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/77e0bdda179022ae38aed8ff64306742d5620922/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L225):

```
NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES = {
  :primary_key => "serial primary key",
  :string      => { :name => "character varying", :limit => 255 },
  #...
```

The closest thing to a specification is in the [Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types):

> These will be mapped onto an appropriate underlying database type, for example with MySQL `:string` is mapped to `VARCHAR(255)`.

But that's not about PostgreSQL and not exactly a guarantee.

---

As an aside, if you're using PostgreSQL, you should almost always go straight to `:text` and pretend that `:string` doesn't exist. PostgreSQL treats them the same internally except that it has to do a length check on `varchar`. There's a bit more discussion on this over here in another one of my answers: [**Changing a column type to longer strings in rails**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694483/479863).

Answer (score 10):

In rails 4 there is no default limit for string type as you can see in the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/77fe87cccd90859e67c958cbf63d7e5662174fd8/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb):

```
NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES = {
        primary_key: "serial primary key",
        bigserial: "bigserial",
        string:      { name: "character varying" },
        text:        { name: "text" },
        #...
```

if you don't specify a limit ActiveRecord will just set `character varying` and you could store there a string of any length as stated in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-character.html):

> If character varying is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size