# Ruby on Rails Models. Why does a decimal{2,1} with scope 1 allow more than digit after the decimal point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, decimal, rails-activerecord

I'm having an issue with a table accepting too many digits after the decimal, despite defining it's precision and scope.

```
rails generate model Hotel name:string 'rating:decimal{2,1}'

class CreateHotels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :hotels do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :rating, precision: 2, scale: 1

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However, I am able to do the following.

```
Hotel.create!(name: “The Holiday Inn”, rating: 3.75)
```

Additionally, I have a rooms table (Room model), with

```
t.decimal :rate, precision: 5, scale: 2 #this holds the room's nightly rate
```

I input 99.99 into this column, but it ends up storing it as 99.98999999..

Why do I have these 2 decimal issues? If I have defined my scope, why am I allowed to input more scope than I have defined?

Comment: What is the version of your Rails?

Comment: Seems like it is a bug in Rails https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4602

Comment: @Pavan That looks like an old bug, the migration in this case matches the generate.

Comment: I'm in version 4.1.0, messing around in IRB.

Answer (score 0):

> I input 99.99 into this column, but it ends up storing it as 99.98999999...

That suggests that you're using SQLite which doesn't really have a `decimal` data type, if you ask SQLite to create a `decimal(m,n)` column it will create a `REAL` instead; `REAL` is a floating point type, not a fixed precision type. To solve this problem, stop using SQLite; odds are that you're not going to deploy a real application on top of SQLite anyway so you should be developing with the same database that you're going to deploy on.

Also, if you're using a fixed precision type for `rating`, you should not say this:

```
Hotel.create!(name: "The Holiday Inn", rating: 3.75)
```

as that 3.75 will be a floating point value in Ruby and it could get messed up before the database sees it. You should say one of these instead:

```
Hotel.create!(name: "The Holiday Inn", rating: '3.75')
Hotel.create!(name: "The Holiday Inn", rating: BigDecimal.new('3.75'))
```

so that you stay well away from floating point front to back.