# How can I change the data type on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to modify the data type from  `string` to `text`, and I followed the tutorial from

[Changing a column type to longer strings in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694273/changing-a-column-type-to-longer-strings-in-rails)

and run `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:rollback`
but it gave me an error message

> == 20160203133535 ChangeNameToProfessors: migrating ===========================
>   -- change_column(:professors, :name, :text)
>   rake aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

How can I solve it?

thank for answering!

Comment: you can start by sharing the actual error you get :)

Comment: give some more error message.

Comment: Please show us the content of your migration file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change a single column:

```
def change
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, :text
end
```

If you want to perform a rollback, then first perform the rollback before changing your (already existing) migration file. You cannot perform a rollback with a changed migration file, this is what likely happens in your scenario.

After the rollback change the migration file to the correct (new) column, and migrate again.

Comment: OP did, as I see in the error message `change_column(:professors, :name, :text)`. something wrong in other place or I dunno.