# What is the right default for the maximum length of a string in rails 4 on postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have a rails (~4.2.3) blogging platform app on postgres (~9.4.0.1), where the title of a post is a string. I want to allow the blog administrator to specify the minimum and maximum length of the title for their blog, so I have title_min_length and title_max_length properties. I want to provide *flexible* defaults for these two values. min_length could, of course be 1. For the max_length, I would like to allow whatever is the *minimum guaranteed maximum length* for a string field in this stack (rails + postgres). What should that value be, given the real limit is the available memory?

According to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354452/456735), there is no limit in Postgres. Also, according to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28539046/456735), as of rails ~4, the ActiveRecord string size limit of 255 has been removed, and a string can be arbitrarily long.

Given that, what is a reasonable maximum length limit to specify as a default? I do not want to artificially restrict the user by picking too short a length.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve informations on your table with MODEL.columns and MODEL.columns_hash.

This will get you how many chars you can store in your column.

```
col_size = Post.columns_hash['title'].limit
```

But from the first answer you linked size depends on how this column is defined, :string or :text, so column size either 255 or 65536. if you don't set limit yourself in migration.